# How can I export an Event Income Detail report to CSV/Excel?

Tags: civireport, export, csv

We find the Event Income Detail report to be useful. But the Actions menu won't let me export this report into a CSV file for some reason.
How can that be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Reports that provide a simple table are more amenable to export as CSV.  The Event Income Detail has different sections to it which does not fit well for a CSV format - what column headings would you use?

Whether a report offers a CSV export option depends on the settings in the code.  The Event Income Detail report is provided by `CRM/Report/Form/Event/Income.php`  You will see a line there saying

```
$this->_csvSupported = FALSE;
```

If you were to change that to `TRUE` then the export option would be shown, but the rest of the report does not handle producing a CSV so that's not useful! ... unless you use that as the starting point to customise it to produce the output you want.

FWIW, pasting into a spreadsheet works pretty well: run the report, highlight the section of the report that you want, copy then paste into a blank LibreOffice spreadsheet, and you often end up with something usable.  That might work with Excel too.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available for Event Income Detail report but CiviCRM is an open source project so you would need to programmatically add this new feature.

Comment: Any idea why export is not available for this report where it is available for other report types?